# Is it possible to use click function on SVG tags? I tried element.click() on a <polygon>. Trying to simulate the click using javascript. Doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, dom, svg

//Trying to retrieve the HTML element  from the below HTML and attempting to click on it using the Javascript code below

```
    <html>
        <svg width="300" height="200">
        <polygon points="100,10 40,198 190,78 10,78 160,198"
  style="fill:lime;stroke:purple;stroke-width:5;fill-rule:evenodd;" />
        </svg>
    </html>

    <script>
        var polygons = document.getElementsByTagName('polygon');
        if(polygons.length>0)
        {
            //This statement doesn't work. Trying to simulate the click on the polygon element. The click function doesn't click it
            polygons[0].click();
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: What is click() supposed to do? Did you want to run some javascript when a polygon is clicked on, if so add an onclick attribute or an event handler for click events.

Comment: Thanks for the reponse Robert. I'm trying to simulate the click on the polygon element using javascript using the DOM click function. But it doesn't click. I tried logging with an onclick function, and no logs get created. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What happens when you click on a polygon, do you call some javascript function? If so just call that javascript function directly.

Comment: I'm trying to do some automation using WPT for performance testing for which it is necessary to click it. For that purpose, I'm simulating the click using javascript.  Other functions get called when it's clicked.  Thanks again.

Comment: What normally happens when you click manually? Call those functions directly in your WPT.

Comment: Thank you for your help Robert. Since, it's for performance I needed to simulate the click to record the timing. So, calling the functions directly wouldn't help. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Contrarily to my fellow, I will purposely and  kindly disregard the fact that you didn't set a click event listener, but will instead answer the question that everyone missed here.

---

The `click` method you are trying to use is the [HTMLElement.click](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click) method.
This method is available to all elements inheriting from HTMLElement, but your `<polygon>` is an SVGPolygonElement, which does not inherit from HTMLElement.

So no, **you can not use this method on this element**, because it has no such method defined in its prototype chain.

```js
// an SVGElement
var poly = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'polygon');
// an HTMLElement
var unknown = document.createElement('foo');

console.log('<polygon> (SVG element)');
console.log('has click method:', !!poly.click);
console.log('inherits from HTMLElement:', poly instanceof HTMLElement);

console.log('//////////////////');

console.log('<foo> (HTML element)');
console.log('has click method:', !!unknown.click);
console.log('inherits from HTMLElement:', unknown instanceof HTMLElement);
```

But even though this method is not available, you can well trigger a click event programmatically, e.g with the [EventTarget.dispatchEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent) method.

```js
var poly = document.getElementById('poly');
poly.dispatchEvent(new Event('click'));

function _log(evt) {
  console.log('clicked');
}
```

```html
<svg>
<polygon id="poly" points="60,20 100,40 100,80 60,100 20,80 20,40" onclick="_log()"/>
</svg>
```

Or since your issue seems to be related to WPT (that I really don't know), it seems that you can also do the same with the [`sendClick`](https://sites.google.com/a/webpagetest.org/docs/using-webpagetest/scripting#TOC-sendClick-sendClickAndWait) method, but once again, I don't know WPT and I just got it from a fast-read of the docs.

Comment: Thank you Kaido. This answered my question clearly. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's quite possible, but you have to add an event listener to the polygon first:

```js
document.querySelector('polygon').addEventListener('click', () => console.log('clicked'));
```

```html
<svg width="300" height="200">
  <polygon points="100,10 40,198 190,78 10,78 160,198"
           style="fill:lime;stroke:purple;stroke-width:5;fill-rule:evenodd;" />
</svg>
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the OPs question. OP wants to programmatically trigger a click event on an element.  Not capture one.